# Is it Possible to Allow Online Radio Users to Select Songs Using Silverlight and Shoutcast?

Tags: silverlight, shoutcast, internet-radio

I don't know where to start...

I have a friend who runs an online radio station. He needs to be able to allow his listeners to somehow automatically request songs - no more than 2x per hour. I do not run the site, but might be able to help him with this project if it is even possible. There has to be a way to list all available songs within his website with buttons next to each song to make requests.

Hope you guys can help, or at least point me in the right direction.

Cheers.

-el

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you're trying to do.  You mention selecting songs, and you also mention requesting.  Are listeners selecting, as in choosing what they want to hear at that time and nobody else hears it?  (i.e. Spotify)  Or, are they requesting, where they pick a song and a DJ (perhaps virtual DJ) plays it later and everyone hears it?

Comment: No matter what you do, don't build it in Silverlight.  It's been deprecated for quite some time now, and is end-of-life this fall.  It's not compatible with much and shouldn't be used.  How you build this out depends on the specifics of what's running server-side.  You'll want to build out a database of music, and an API service to enumerate the music for website visitors.  Also, I don't know the specifics of your situation but consider that this counts as "interactive" streaming by most content licenses, which has significant extra cost and needs to be agreed to ahead of time.

Comment: I don't use Spotify, or virtual DJ... I just want this station to be able to let listeners like me be able to request a song or two, and have it automatically be queued up in a real time play list. After the play list is exhausted, the random song selection is selected by default.

Comment: I am just trying to help out an online friend, so I have no idea what he is running on his server. I assume the "database of music" should be in SQL? As for the "API service to enumerate the music for website visitors", you lost me there. "Also, I don't know the specifics of your situation but consider that this counts as 'interactive' streaming by most content licenses, which has significant extra cost and needs to be agreed to ahead of time..." I will research this when sober. Thx so much for the info! Cheers!